# Is there any module for importing news from a WordPress site?

Tags: importing-exporting

When we install Drupal, the first thing we do is importing content from other engines that we used.

Is there any kind of similar converters from other engines, for posts, user accounts, and comments?

Comment: there are several drupal migrate modules

Comment: mention that If anyone search and find this article read your tips.

Answer (score 6):

For Drupal 7 try [WordPress Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/wordpress_migrate):

> wordpress_migrate supports migrating WordPress blog exports (WXR
>   format) into Drupal using the Migrate module. Import of posts, pages,
>   comments, attachments, tags and categories is supported. Imports can
>   be rolled back completely.

and [Wordpress Import](http://drupal.org/project/wordpress_import) if you are using Drupal 6:

> This module imports a WordPress blog into Drupal from a WordPress
>   eXtended RSS (WXR) file.

Comment: Keep in mind that WXR exports from Wordpress don't always end up as valid XML.  When this happens, the imports may fail.  This may be fixed now, but I have had problems with exports from sites that use plugins that inline Javascript into posts.