# How to synchronize my Drupal site with content pulled from a Wordpress site?

Tags: 7

I need a solution which asks to another site (running WordPress) for updates (i.e., I want to pull new content posted on a WordPress site into Drupal.

Please note that I need a regular (daily) sync of the contents, not a single import.

How can I implement this?
Can I read the site RSS? Or can I ask in some other way this data?
And how?

Comment: Do you want to pull WP content into Drupal, or push Drupal content to Wordpress?

Comment: Pull WP content into Drupal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any module for importing news from a WordPress site?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/54411/16495)

Comment: Nope, I need a daily sync of the contents not a single import.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress exports its content using RSS.  The standard way of pulling this content on a regular basis is to configure the core RSS **Aggregator** module (disabled by default) to pull the content from the WordPress RSS.  It is highly configurable, you can pull daily or by the hour.

Here is a link to an [introduction](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/aggregator/) to the Drupal Aggregator - quoting:

> Aggregator is a key part of Drupal that is often ignored.
>
> I blame it on the confusing name. No, Aggregator is not an animal in Florida that eats people. Aggregator is a module that imports content from RSS feeds into Drupal.
>
> Because it has a name starting with "A", Aggregator is the first module that people ever see on the Modules page. In this tutorial, we're going to show you what Aggregator does and how to use it.